# Taxonomy menu limited to certain number of terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Wondering if anyone can steer me in the right direction on this. I'd like to have a taxonomy menu where I have a few main terms listed with with around 5-7 children terms. When the user is on the page of the main taxonomy term, all of the child terms are shown.

For example, when the user is on the home taxonomy page that lists all of the terms then the menu would show this:

```
-Term 1
--Term A
--Term B
--Term C
--Term D
<more>

-Term 2
--Term A
--Term B
--Term C
--Term D
<more>
```

Clicking on  or clicking on the Term 1 page would then show all of the children of Term 1:

```
-Term 1
--Term A
--Term B
--Term C
--Term D
--Term E
--Term F
--Term G

-Term 2
--Term A
--Term B
--Term C
--Term D
<more>
```

Here is a [link to a site](http://kelbytraining.com/online/courses/) that already does this and that is where I got the idea.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: how are the path going to be for the taxonomy page is it like the example?

Comment: @MohammedShameem yes, I am planning on having Terms 1,2,3 and then having children for each of them. But no children for the children. Only 2 levels.

Comment: what about the path of them? is it going to be somepath/term-1 for the parent and somepath/term-1/term-a for the child term or is it going to be somepath/term-a for the children

Comment: @Dan, have you done something?

Comment: Good question! All terms are under the /videos. So it will be /videos/term-a. There is no hierarchy in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this is to create a view that block displays a set number of items in a list (HTML or unformatted list), with a global text field that will link to your term page. You can then style this with css to look like the rest of your menus (if you require to).

This unfortunately will mean that it will not go through the drupal core menu system. You will have to create your own "Admin" view to manage this "menu". I would suggest [Draggable Views](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) if you require a webmaster to control the sort order.